# Convert enter key to space in php?

Tags: php

I have this string :

```
$msg = 'A:1509 B:54
1.NS:22
2.TR:56
3.MD:547
4.STS:22
5.SR:15 ';
```

it would show normal horizontal string. but the variable separated by enter key.... 
how to convert the enter key to space. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace any `\r` or `\n` characters. You can do that like this:

```
$msg = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "  "), ' ', $msg);
```

This replaces anything in the `array("\r", "\n", "  ")` with a space and assigns the new value back to `$msg`. (The last entry is to address the point from the comments that `\r\n` would result in two spaces.)

Comment: Should the needle array be `array("\r\n",\n")` to avoid leaving 2 spaces?

Comment: @Terminus good point. I tweaked my answer, though I took a slightly different approach to catch any standalone `\r`s.

Comment: That'd work unless there are any double spaces in the original input. Which doesn't look to be the case for this question. +1.

Comment: Would there ever be a case where a \r is all alone? Besides someone running a find and replace and removing just the \n I mean ;)

Comment: @Terminus possibly. Without knowing more about the OP's data, I can't say. I know that I have seen files before (CSV files from a financial firm) that inexplicably used `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` interchangeably, sometimes even within a single file. So, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get all of the contents onto one line? You could try replacing the new line characters

`$msg = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $msg);`

Comment: Still return like this
'
string 'Area:1509 tps:54
1.ZS:22
2.BR:56
3.MF:547
4.STS:22
5.SR:15 ' (length=59)'

Comment: sorry stackoverflow.com automatically strip the enter. but seems your not work

Answer (score 0):

This is how to handle it:

```
 $msg = str_replace(chr(0x0D), ' ', $msg);
 $msg = str_replace(chr(0x0A), ' ', $msg);
```